# wp-admin page redirecting to 404 error page

Tags: wp-admin

I updated my Wordpress site to 4.0.1 from 3.8.5 and now I can't access my wp-admin page. It redirects to a 404 error page. I've already tried deactivating my plugins by renaming my plugin folder via CPanel.

www.kristinleeb.com

Comment: If you have access to the db, go to the `wp_options` table, and change the `template` and `stylesheet` options (options 44 and 45) to `twentyfourteen`. This will ensure that the bundled theme, twentyfourteen loads. Check if you can login now. If you can, you will need to search in your theme for that problem. Also turn debug on

Comment: Just tried this, no luck. Still redirects to 404/page not found ager changing template and stylesheet options to twentyfourteen.

Comment: If all plugins are deactivated and a bundled theme is activated, then something has broken your htaccess. Have a look at that.

Comment: problem is resolved but no solution acquired. I ended up accidentally deleting my entire site (public_html folder) and working with my host to restore properly.

Comment: Great, glad you were able to resolve it. Enjoy :-)